# Why does changing the OnDelete behaviour generates an empty migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a model in which I defined a one-to-one relation previously something like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasOne(parent => parent.Info)
            .WithOne(info => info.Parent)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

which generated a migration with a foreign key like this:

```
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Info_Parent_ParentId",
                        column: x => x.ParentId,
                        principalTable: "Info",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

As I see it, a one-to-one relation does not have to be restricted on delete, so I want to change the relation to Cascade On Delete:

```
          .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

However, when I generate a new migration for this change, both Up() and Down() are empty.
What could be the reason?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into what EF calls "Owned" objects. These are specifically for one-to-one relationships. Perhaps if you classified it as such, you would be able to achieve your goal. See the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities